# SharePoint Workflow and starting EXE file

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2010

I'd like to create a SharePoint 2010 workflow that calls and EXE file and waits for the file to execute and then perform some actions. I can't seem to find any references to calling and EXE file or any other program from a SharePoint Workflow. Can I accomplish this in Sharepoint Designer? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to call an EXE file directly from a workflow. The closest thing supported by WF is communication with local services. However, it is complicated and definitely cannot be done in SharePoint Designer.

- [Using Local Services in Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735947%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [Workflow Services for Local Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335718.aspx)
- [Using the HandleExternalEventActivity Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734592%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [Using the CallExternalMethodActivity Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734739%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marek. The EXE file downloads TAB delimited files via FTP and imports the data into a SQL Server DB.

Comment: @August Blaze If you're up to some custom coding, it's something that can be done inside a custom workflow activity or even better two separate activities - first for FTP communication (you can also consider buying this one - 3rd party solutions exist) and second to import the data.